# Proguard not renaming my activity classes?

Tags: android, proguard

I am using Proguard in my android project it neither Obfuscate classes name that extends from Activity nor its overridden methods like onCreate, `onCreateOptionsMenu` etc. Here is the code

```
-optimizationpasses 5

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses

-dontpreverify

-verbose

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-repackageclasses 'mystore'

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {

    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {

    public static <fields>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's as expected - you don't want it to rename those classes since they are referenced from the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Similarly since the methods are called from external code, it can't rename the methods either otherwise that code won't find them.

Comment: Then i have to write code in any new method and make it called in overridden methods.Anyway thanks
!